# ASP.NET Version of PHPList

Tags: asp.net, phplist

Is there an ASP.NET version of phplist???

For those that do not know what phplist is; it's a list management app with a lot of really helpful features.  (phplist.com)

I want to use something like phplist in a hosted Windows website without having to pay for another account that's just Linux to run phplist and a web service for me to access.

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard about phplist. But you can [run php using iis](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/09/19/How-to-install-PHP-on-IIS7-_2800_RC1_2900_.aspx) as well. Why not try it?

Comment: I know that I can do that, but my web host does not support it on their Windows hosted accounts.  If I open up a new hosting account in addition to the one I have then I know I can do that.  Hopefully someone knows of a .NET version of phplist.